# How to create shape with borders?

Tags: css, border, z-index, shapes

I want to create a black graphical element with a border that is positioned above the video feed pictured.

I have tried using :before and :after but the border complicates things. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

You can see in the photo that the feed is going below the border, since the graphic element is currently a square with a border radius

The below code is how I created the shape as pictured, but it is faulty since the feed goes above the border:

[image]

```css
div.wrap1{
    position: fixed;
    height: 90vh;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 80vw;
    margin-left: -120px;

    .graphic-bg-1{
        z-index: 5;
        border: 3px solid #3AD8FF;
        border-bottom: none;
        border-radius: 120px;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .mask{
        position: absolute;
        height: 500px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: black;
        bottom: 0;
        // margin-left: -120px;
        z-index: 6;
     }
 }

 div.wrap2{
     position: fixed;
     height: 75vh;
     width: 100vw;
     right: 0;
     bottom: 10vh;
     margin-right: calc(-80vw + 123px);
     z-index: 7;

     .graphic-bg-2{
         z-index: 8;
         border: 3px solid #3AD8FF;
         border-top: transparent;
         border-radius: 120px;
         position: relative;
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
     }

     .mask2{
         position: absolute;
         height: 109px;
         width: calc(100% - 3px);
         background-color: black;
         top: 0;
         right: 0;
         z-index: 8;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.first-element {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
  float: left;
}

.secound-element {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 70px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
  margin-left: -1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-element"></div>
<div class="secound-element"></div>
```

[Try this it might helpful](https://codepen.io/hardenrahul/pen/XePOpX)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17624596)

Comment: yes, u are right. I should place my code here. and that I doing right after this comment.